# mongoDB, replicaSet: Replication has not yet been configured

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

I am trying to install a ReplicaSet with the help of the following manual:
[https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/]
However, I always get that error:

> Replication has not yet been configured

my code in OpenSUSE terminal 
`sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost`


/etc/mongod.conf does have the following line:

```
replication:
        replSetName: "rs0"
```

Anyone who could help me here? Would appreciate that!

Comment: You have to initiate the replica set.

Comment: Unless you specify config file like `mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf` your config file does not have any effect.

Comment: According to my little knowledge, initiating the replica set is possible after I have entered the mongo shell on an active mongo. Is this info wrong?

okay, I don't specify the config file. However, I do specify the name of the replicaSet I want to create. Yet, I get this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities to start mongod

```
sudo mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongo --replSet rs0 --bind_ip localhost
```

OR (when all those parameters, port, dbpath, bindIp... Are set in the [config-file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/))

```
sudo mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Now mongod is running and it knows that it should be replica set.

Connect to that RS with 'mongo' command. You get answer like "MongoDB shell version v4.0.19" and prompt '>' where cursor is waiting your next command.

Now you need (only once) to initiate this replica set, give next command:

```
rs.initiate()
```

Now your prompt should be changed to

```
rs0:PRIMARY>
```

And you can "ask" now your replica set status

```
rs.status()
```

Or the configuration

```
rs.conf()
```